# Mutiplicación con JSF

Tags: jsf

estoy empezando a usar Java Server Faces y me han propuesto verificar una multiplicación y que muestre si el resultado es correcto o no. El tema es que al darle al botón verificar me da error y no se a que pueda deberse. Adjunto el código de la clase java y el index.xhtml.

Multiplicacion.java

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

public class Multiplicacion {

    private String resultado;

    public String getResultado() {
        return this.resultado;
    }

    public void setResultado(String resultado) {
        this.resultado = resultado;
    }

    public String validacion(){
        if (this.resultado.equals("21")) return "ok"; 
        else return "ko";
    }

}
```

Archivo index.xhtml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
 <title>Verificación de una multiplicación</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
 <b>Introduzca el resultado de la siguiente multiplicación:</b>
 <h:form>
  <p>7 x 4 = <h:inputText value="#{Multiplicacion.resultado}" /></p>
  <h:commandButton value="Verificar" action="#{Multiplicacion.validacion}"/>
 </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola @Flaxx bienvenido a SF, para poder ayudarte correctamente puedes decirme que versión de JSF , JDK y Servidor de Aplicaciones utilizas. Ademas si puedes agregar el error que tienes para poder analizarlo.

Comment: Hola buenas, ya he conseguido resolver el problema. El problema era que estaba usando como referencia otro ejercicio de Login con JSF y al intentar trabajar con el se me habia olvidado cambiar los nombres en el archivo faces-config.xml y me decia que Multiplicación.resultado tenía valor null. Gracias por responder de todas formas. Un saludo :)